# How to get HTML button in the browser print in VS Studio Code terminal?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I have written a simple HTML and JavaScript code that should print on the VS Studio Code terminal whenever the button is pressed in the browser. But the button is not printing anything. Do I have to change any VS code settings for this?
Here is the JavaScript and HTML code respectively :

```js
function print()
{
    console.log("Button Pressed");
}
```

```html
<body>

    <section id="print-section">
        <button id="print" onclick="print()">Print</button>            
    </section>
    
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
    
</body>
```

Comment: You can see the log in browser console.

Comment: JavaScript runs in a sandbox in the browser, it will never output outside browser or be able to read/write files in the file system, Use NodeJS if you want that

Answer (score 0):

You should check the browser's console in its developer tools. Visual studio code's terminal is your local system terminal. JavaScript that runs on a browser will print to the browser's console.